# Ubuntu 13.04 Wifi Keeps on Cutting off

Tags: wireless, 13.04

Ubuntu keeps on cutting off and whenever it does it asks for the password and it doesn't accept it.

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8191SEvA Wireless LAN Controller [10ec:8171] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1467]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8192se
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1605]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

I've heard people want this information too. So here you go.

Comment: Does this still happen when you are close to the router? I only ask because its what my laptop and phone do when they see a hotspot but the signal is week. The icon isn't always accurate :/

Comment: @namingFailed Well my laptop is underground most of the time and my connection isn't that great too. But overall it doesn't.

Comment: OK, just thought I'd clear up easy answers.

Comment: @namingFailed Do you think I should move closer to the router?

Comment: Just test that the problem doesn't go away in best case.  If not sometimes turning WiFi off on the case and only on after booting helps